# How to create a list of users who did not submit some webform?

Tags: views, webforms

I have a webform expecting all users to record their data online.

I would like to list all users who did not submit the webform yet.
I have been trying to use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), but I cannot find a way to do that.

To list users who have submitted is not a problem, just display the users submitting in Views table.

How can I list all users who did not submit the webform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1 - Introduce a webform submission flag

Install/enable the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.
Navigate to `/admin/structure/flags/add/node` and create a flag (do not check the "global" checkbox). Let's assume you label it something like "*Webform submission*". For "Bundles" (on the same form), check "Webform".

Here is such Flag definition (in export format) you could use for it (just import it in your own site):

```
$flags = array();
// Exported flag: "Webform submission".
$flags['webform_submission'] = array (
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'title' => 'Webform submission',
  'global' => '0',
  'types' => 
  array (
    0 => 'webform',
  ),
  'flag_short' => 'Webform submitted',
  'flag_long' => 'Indication that the Webform was submitted already',
  'flag_message' => 'Webform submission recorded',
  'unflag_short' => 'Webform NOT submitted',
  'unflag_long' => 'Indication that the Webform is not yet submitted',
  'unflag_message' => 'Webform submission recording removed',
  'unflag_denied_text' => '',
  'link_type' => 'toggle',
  'weight' => 0,
  'show_in_links' => 
  array (
    'full' => 0,
    'teaser' => 0,
    'rss' => 0,
    'search_index' => 0,
    'search_result' => 0,
    'answers_full_node' => 0,
    'print' => 0,
  ),
  'show_as_field' => 0,
  'show_on_form' => 0,
  'access_author' => '',
  'show_contextual_link' => 0,
  'i18n' => 0,
  'api_version' => 3,
);
return $flags;
```

## Step 2 - Register webform submissions

Install/enable the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and create a Rule to flag the webform when it is submitted (by the user who submitted the webform and using the flag "Webform submission" (from Step 1).

Here is such Rule definition (in export format) you could use for it (just import it in your own site, which you can do if you have the 'Rules UI' enabled):

```
{ "rules_flag_a_submitted_webform" : {
    "LABEL" : "Flag a submitted webform",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "flag", "webform_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:nid" ], "value" : "5" } },
      { "user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "user" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "flag_flagnode" : {
          "flag" : "webform_submission",
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "flagging_user" : [ "user" ],
          "permission_check" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## Step 3 - List the webform submissions

Create a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module), to list the user who have yes or no flagged the webform with the "Webform submission"-flag from Step 1).

Here is such Views definition (in export format) you could use for it (just import it in your own site, which you can do if you have the 'Views UI' enabled):

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'webform_submissions_by_users';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Webform submissions by users';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Webform submissions by users';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relationship: Flags: User's flaggings */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_user_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_user_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_user_content_rel']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_user_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_user_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_user_content_rel']['required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_user_content_rel']['flag'] = 'webform_submission';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Flags: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['relationship'] = 'flag_user_content_rel';
/* Field: Flags: Flagged time */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['relationship'] = 'flag_user_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Sort criterion: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Filter criterion: Flags: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['relationship'] = 'flag_user_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['value'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'uid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['label'] = 'User uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['use_operator'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['operator'] = 'uid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'webform-submissions-by-users';
```

## Fruit of your labor

If you import the above definitions of the flag, the rule and the view, and you have a few users submit the webform (= record their data), you can visit the relative path in your own site, which should then display a table that looks similar to this example:

```
Name            User uid   Flagged time
--------------+----------+--------------------------------
Demo.User     !          !                                
Famous.Dries  ! 8        ! Wednesday, May 11, 2016 - 19:13
Pierre.Vriens ! 19       ! Wednesday, May 11, 2016 - 18:07
```

For the above example, user "Demo.User" had not yet submitted the webform. The view contains an exposed filter so that you can limit the display to only those who submitted the form, or those who did not yet submit the form.

## Start nagging users

If you would enhance your view from Step 3 with the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, and you'd create a Rules Component (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) to send an eMail, you could use it to eMail all those users in that view with some type of nagging eMail like "*Please record your data...*".

## What's next?

The above doesn't take into account any webform submissions from before the above logic is implement. However it should be pretty forward to use a mixture of the above (4) modules, including VBO, to perform such one time only update (to also flag the users who already submitted the webform in the past). Anybody interested in knowing about that: [Ask (a followup) Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ...

Comment: It looks this is the answer. However If you could provide in a more detail, especially for step 2 and 3. I never create rules. I tried in my local machine but not successful, not sure in step 2 and 3.

Comment: @WaluyoAdiSiswanto : here is your chance to get started with the rules module ... See my expanded answer. I hope it won't get **[Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)**-ged when somebody re-**[Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)** it with something like not compliant to the **[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)** of this site ...

Comment: The additional information is pretty clear and it works. The only thing I need to adjust is the nid for the webform. I just need to change the nid 5 to my webform nid. Since this does not account any submission before the logic applied, I need to know how to include all previous submissions as well.

Comment: Why is this such a complex answer for something so simple? Users shouldn't need to install two additional modules for this.

Answer (score 2):

Well above solution may work but it looks far too complex to my eyes. ;)

I have achieved this on Drupal 8 by following below steps,

1. Create a user view
2. Load user data into fields
3. Add relationship to "webform submissions" (Do not enable "Require this relationship")
4. Add filter "Webform submission: Submitted by"
5. Set that filter to "Is Empty (NULL)"

This will show all users who have not submitted any webform.

to target a specific webform, create a user role and give access to only that role for that specific webform.

Or there is another filter, where you can select specific webform but somehow it does not work on my drupal site. You can give it a try, it may work on your drupal site.

This should also work for Drupal 7, I haven't tried it.

Enjoy :)